# Sort by multiple criteria

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a column that looks like this :

```
0      // Red colored
0      // Red colored
0 (1)  // Orange colored
0 (2)  // Red colored
0      // Orange colored
0      // Red colored
0 (24) // Orange colored
0 (4)  // Red colored
0      // Orange colored
0 (3)  // Orange colored
1     
1
1 (7)
2
2 (3)
2
... etc
```

I would get the following order :

```
0      // Red colored
0      // Red colored
0      // Red colored
0 (24) // Red colored
0 (4)  // Red colored
0 (2)  // Red colored
0      // Orange colored
0      // Orange colored
0 (4)  // Orange colored
0 (1)  // Orange colored
1     
1
1 (7)
2
2 (3)
2
... etc
```

I want to order this column in datatables using these 3 criteria : first order by number (0's), then by color (red first), then by number un parantheses (the highest first).

I've got in each `data-order` the following format : `0r24` which means the first number is zero, the color is red, the number in the parantheses is 24. Repeat for all others.

I tried to play with the `columnDefs` attribute of Datatables to get my result by doing the following :

```
"columnDefs": [
    {
        "type": "num-fmt", 
        "targets": 7
    }, {
        "targets": [7], 
        "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
            return type === 'sort' ?
                   row[7]['@data-order'].replace(/r/g,'0').replace(/o/g,'1') : row[7]['@data-order'];
         }
     }
]
```

Here I am trying to replace the letters `o` and `r` with `0` and `1` to be able to have an all numeric value for it to order upon, but it doesn't work. Any idea how to make this work and do the following as I explained?

Comment: Are the actual source values `"Red colored"` and `"Orange colored"`?

Comment: @axelduch yes, my comment means that the color of the zero is orange or red.